# mssql Node.JS returning more than expected results and making REST calls difficult to parse

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server

Node.js  mssql package

For documentation look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#json-support)

Given this for the config:

```
  exports.dbConfig = {
        user: 'App',
        password: 'App',
        server: '\\SQLEXPRESS',
        database: 'Game',
        port: 1433,
        parseJSON: true
    };
```

DDL for Players table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players](
    [PlayerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ScreenName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EMail] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [LastLogin] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [FirstLogin] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastSeen] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [GamesWon] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GamesPlayed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProSubscriptionEnd] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [UserPermissionLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PlayerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And this for the query:

```
db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Players For JSON PATH, Root(\'Players\') ",
```

I expect this result based on the documentation.  Note what's I think I should get is just the recordset, once, but I'm getting "Recordsets" and the single recordset, then repeat of the recordset.   Parsing this out on a REST call is not working out well.

```
"recordset": [
    {
        "Players": [
            {
                "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ScreenName": "Steve",
                "EMail": "steve.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "GamesWon": 3,
                "GamesPlayed": 5,
                "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                "UserPermissionLevel": 0
            },
            {
                "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                "ScreenName": "JIm",
                "EMail": "Jim.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                "GamesWon": 3,
                "GamesPlayed": 5,
                "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                "UserPermissionLevel": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I am getting this.

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Players": [
                    {
                        "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "ScreenName": "Steve",
                        "EMail": "steve.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                        "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "GamesWon": 3,
                        "GamesPlayed": 5,
                        "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                       "UserPermissionLevel": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                        "ScreenName": "JIm",
                        "EMail": "Jim.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                        "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "GamesWon": 3,
                        "GamesPlayed": 5,
                        "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                        "UserPermissionLevel": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "Players": [
                {
                    "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "ScreenName": "Steve",
                    "EMail": "steve.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                    "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "GamesWon": 3,
                    "GamesPlayed": 5,
                    "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                   "UserPermissionLevel": 0
                },
                {
                    "PlayerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                    "ScreenName": "JIm",
                    "EMail": "Jim.moss@winecountrywoodworking.com",
                    "LastLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "FirstLogin": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "LastSeen": "1956-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "GamesWon": 3,
                    "GamesPlayed": 5,
                    "ProSubscriptionEnd": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
                   "UserPermissionLevel": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        2
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the definition of Players table

Comment: By adding this to the response I am able to parse down to the single recordset, and to the Json data that I need.

    recordset.recordsets[0][1]);

Comment: @Gabriele Franco

DDML for player table added.